# CSS video not stretching to 100% width of parent container

Tags: html, css

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top-rated-container-1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.video-container video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<section class="top-rated-container-1">
        <div class="video-container">
            <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline=""
                poster="https://a.ltrbxd.com/resized/sm/upload/6x/g7/m0/1h/step-0-1400-0-788-crop.jpg?k=33dfcdf72e">
                <source src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/sm/upload/lq/7m/3m/f0/highest-rated-eeaao-720p-2k.webm?k=cfa68eefb2"
                    type="video/webm">
                <source src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/sm/upload/37/1y/9b/s0/highest-rated-eeaao-720p-2k.mp4?k=594f85a26b"
                    type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </section>
```

I have a video element in my HTML code and I have specified its width to be 100% in the CSS. However, the video is not taking up the full width of its container and I cannot figure out why. I have tried overriding conflicting styles and checking the width of the parent container, but the issue persists. I am looking for a solution to make the video element take up 100% of the width of its container.

I have tried specifying the width of the video element to be 100% in the CSS and also tried setting an absolute value for the width using pixels. I expected the video to take up the full width of its container, but it did not. The video element is not stretching to fill the width of the container, and I am not sure what is causing the issue.

I also tried setting the height of the video element to `auto`, but it still took the height of the entire screen. I kinda like to have a certain height but stretched 100%, like the photo below.

The output should look like this.
[image]

Comment: it's because you have the `height` set (`height: 250px;`) and the video keeps the aspect ratio taking the max width it can according to that height.

Comment: and the video element is width:100%. inspect it with browser console. As @DiegoD if your remove the fixed height the video shows 100%

Comment: the point is that if you remove that `height`, the video will take 100% of the width and won't be constrained

Comment: looking at the latest edit, it seems what you are looking for is stretching the width of the video as 100% of the available width (while keeping the video aspect ratio) but yet crop(!) it so that the height will be fixed. And by the way.. no, the width 100% accomodates the height according to its aspect ratio.. it doesn't take 100% height (it would be a side effect if the whole page wasn't taller than that height). `height: auto` translates to zero usually.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Yes, that's exactly what I am looking for. I kinda understand now that the video width should accommodate the height according to its aspect ratio and height. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add, if you want to make the video element responsive, you can use CSS **object-fit.** You can set the object-fit property to "cover" which will stretch the video to fill the container while maintaining its aspect ratio:

```
.video-container video {
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
object-fit: cover;
}
```

Or you can set object-fit property to "contain" which will scale the video down to fit inside the container while maintaining its aspect ratio:

```
.video-container video {
width: 100%;
height: 150px;
object-fit: contain;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add `object-fit: fill` to the `<video>`:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top-rated-container-1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.video-container video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: fill;
}
```

```html
<section class="top-rated-container-1">
        <div class="video-container">
            <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline=""
                poster="https://a.ltrbxd.com/resized/sm/upload/6x/g7/m0/1h/step-0-1400-0-788-crop.jpg?k=33dfcdf72e">
                <source src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/sm/upload/lq/7m/3m/f0/highest-rated-eeaao-720p-2k.webm?k=cfa68eefb2"
                    type="video/webm">
                <source src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/sm/upload/37/1y/9b/s0/highest-rated-eeaao-720p-2k.mp4?k=594f85a26b"
                    type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </section>
```

EDIT: since OP edited the question, seems like `object-fit: cover` is what's needed here:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top-rated-container-1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.video-container video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="top-rated-container-1">
        <div class="video-container">
            <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline=""
                poster="https://a.ltrbxd.com/resized/sm/upload/6x/g7/m0/1h/step-0-1400-0-788-crop.jpg?k=33dfcdf72e">
                <source src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/sm/upload/lq/7m/3m/f0/highest-rated-eeaao-720p-2k.webm?k=cfa68eefb2"
                    type="video/webm">
                <source src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/sm/upload/37/1y/9b/s0/highest-rated-eeaao-720p-2k.mp4?k=594f85a26b"
                    type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: thats not responsive

Comment: @prioa the OP specifically added `height: 250px` and seem to only want to stretch the width, unless i'm missing something, I don't think the OP wants it to be responsive

Comment: you are right :D

Comment: Using `object-fit` property works. Thanks for this!

Answer (score 1):

- Issue in the code : You have set a height to the video. you can set it to **auto** or try **object-fit: cover;**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.top-rated-container-1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.video-container video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<section class="top-rated-container-1">
  <div class="video-container">
    <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline="" poster="https://a.ltrbxd.com/resized/sm/upload/6x/g7/m0/1h/step-0-1400-0-788-crop.jpg?k=33dfcdf72e">
                <source src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/sm/upload/lq/7m/3m/f0/highest-rated-eeaao-720p-2k.webm?k=cfa68eefb2"
                    type="video/webm">
                <source src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/sm/upload/37/1y/9b/s0/highest-rated-eeaao-720p-2k.mp4?k=594f85a26b"
                    type="video/mp4">
            </video>
  </div>
</section>
```

*If you need a solution without changing the height please comment below. I'll find a solution. Thanks :)*

Comment: I tried setting the height  of the video element to auto, but it still took the height of the entire screen. I kinda like to have a certain height and should stretched 100%.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Ok. then you can use    object-fit: cover;    
I think now the issue will be fix : )

Comment: I have edited my answer. Run and check it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make the video Responsive and don´t wanna give a height (this can be the case for obvious reasons) you can use the `aspect-ratio` property. (this is always a good idea :))

If you want to take just 250px in height from the video, its a better idea to give the parent element the 250px. so the video wouldnt be stretched out.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top-rated-container-1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height:250px;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  overflow:hidden
}
.video-container video {
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  aspect-ratio: 308 / 125;
  object-fit:fill
}
```

```html
<section class="top-rated-container-1">
        <div class="video-container">
            <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline=""
                poster="https://a.ltrbxd.com/resized/sm/upload/6x/g7/m0/1h/step-0-1400-0-788-crop.jpg?k=33dfcdf72e">
                <source src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/sm/upload/lq/7m/3m/f0/highest-rated-eeaao-720p-2k.webm?k=cfa68eefb2"
                    type="video/webm">
                <source src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/sm/upload/37/1y/9b/s0/highest-rated-eeaao-720p-2k.mp4?k=594f85a26b"
                    type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: It works too, thanks for this! Just wondering, how did you calculate the `308 / 125` values for aspect -ratio? I'm looking rn  in the MDN Documentation and this are the examples: aspect-ratio: 1 / 1;
aspect-ratio: 16 / 9;
aspect-ratio: 0.5;

Comment: online caluclator :) https://calculateaspectratio.com/

Answer (score 0):

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.top-rated-container-1 {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.video-container {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.video-container video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<section class="top-rated-container-1">
        <div class="video-container">
            <video autoplay="" loop="" muted="" playsinline=""
                poster="https://a.ltrbxd.com/resized/sm/upload/6x/g7/m0/1h/step-0-1400-0-788-crop.jpg?k=33dfcdf72e">
                <source src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/sm/upload/lq/7m/3m/f0/highest-rated-eeaao-720p-2k.webm?k=cfa68eefb2"
                    type="video/webm">
                <source src="https://a.ltrbxd.com/sm/upload/37/1y/9b/s0/highest-rated-eeaao-720p-2k.mp4?k=594f85a26b"
                    type="video/mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).